# Dictionary not storing values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have problem with my dictionary named "list" because when I call method `removePeople` or `saveToFile` from menu after adding one person, it doesn't print or save anything. When I comment loop in `Main` and creating instance of class `Person` and then call all methods manually it works. What am I missing here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace scope_and_accessibility
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool menu = true; 
        while (menu)
          {
             menu = Menu();
          } 
    }
    public static bool Menu()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        int choice;
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add person");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Delete person");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Save data to text file");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Exit");
        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                person.createPerson();
                return true;
            case 2:
                person.removePeople();
                return true;
            case 3:
                person.saveToFile();
                return true;
            case 4:
                return false;
            default:
                return true;
        }

    }
}
class Person
{
    private long choiceOfPerson = 0;
    private string completeInfo = "";
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public long personalIdentityNumber { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    DateTime dateOfBirth = new DateTime();
    Dictionary<long, string> list = new Dictionary<long, string>();

    public void createPerson()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter personal identity number");
        personalIdentityNumber = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your first Name");
        firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your last name");
        lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your gender");
        Gender = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth: DD/MM/YYYY");
        bool error = true;
        {
            while (error)
                try
                {
                    dateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    error = false;
                }
                catch (FormatException fEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fEx.Message);

                }
        }
        completeInfo = firstName + " " + lastName + " " + Gender + " " + dateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        list.Add(personalIdentityNumber, completeInfo);
    }
    public void removePeople()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<long, string> entry in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(completeInfo + " " + personalIdentityNumber);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Write the perosnal identity number of person you wish to delete");
        choiceOfPerson = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        list.Remove(choiceOfPerson);
    }
    public void saveToFile()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<long, string> entry in list)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"E:\gry\info2.txt", completeInfo + personalIdentityNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's because in `Menu` you create a new person with it's own `list` every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list of person is set inside your Person class. If you create a new instance of Person, the other one is destroyed. Instead, you should keep your list reference outside Person and put it inside your Program class.

You should only manipulate your list from outside the Person class. The Person class is just an object representing your Person. It cannot contain a list of itself.

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<long, string> list = new Dictionary<long, string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool menu = true; 
        while (menu)
          {
             menu = Menu();
          } 
    }
    public static bool Menu()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        int choice;
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add person");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Delete person");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Save data to text file");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Exit");
        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                person.createPerson();
                var personInfoKey = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", person.firstName, person.lastName, person.Gender, person.dateOfBirth); 
                list.Add(person, personInfoKey );
                return true;
            case 2:
                person.removePeople();
                list.Remove(person);
                return true;
            case 3:
                person.saveToFile();
                return true;
            case 4:
                return false;
            default:
                return true;
        }

    }
}
class Person
{
    private long choiceOfPerson = 0;
    private string completeInfo = "";
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public long personalIdentityNumber { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    DateTime dateOfBirth = new DateTime();

    public void createPerson()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter personal identity number");
        personalIdentityNumber = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your first Name");
        firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your last name");
        lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your gender");
        Gender = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth: DD/MM/YYYY");
        bool error = true;
        {
            while (error)
                try
                {
                    dateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    error = false;
                }
                catch (FormatException fEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fEx.Message);

                }
        }
        completeInfo = firstName + " " + lastName + " " + Gender + " " + dateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        list.Add(personalIdentityNumber, completeInfo);
    }
    public void removePeople()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<long, string> entry in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(completeInfo + " " + personalIdentityNumber);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Write the perosnal identity number of person you wish to delete");
        choiceOfPerson = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        list.Remove(choiceOfPerson);
    }
    public void saveToFile()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<long, string> entry in list)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"E:\gry\info2.txt", completeInfo + personalIdentityNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might aswell want to put the CreatePerson, Remove, etc. method inside your Program class, to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

your "list" is in the scope of your Person class.  It needs to be in the scope of your Program class.

Answer (score -2):

```
using System.Linq;

var text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine), list.Select(entry => $"
                         {completeInfo} {personalIdentityNumber}"));
File.WriteAllText(path, text);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Why and how does this solve the problem? Those who can answer those questions for themselves don't need someone else's code.